# How to use filters in Arrays similar to 'Like" clause in SQL for AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular5

Is there any way to use a **LIKE** filter for arrays in Angular5? I can only use the filter function for the arrays, but it needs to match the exact filter to be able to fetch the element.

```
this.myArray= this.myArray2.filter(myClass => myClass.name == value);
```

What I want is if `value == 'mar'`, it would return all elements of the array with the names with `'mar'` in it (e.g. Mark, Romar, Smarts, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the string method `includes()`:

```
this.myArray= this.myArray2.filter(element => element.name.includes(value));
```

See the following link to read about the `includes()` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes